# Least-square-method statistic (EDIT IN MY LAST ANSWER)

Tags: statistics, least-squares, maximum-likelihood

Good evening, I have a problem with the least-square-method in statistic:

I've looked for an example and I found this: In the book << Springer Series in Statistics >> by D. Brillinger, page 294, there is a table. This table shows an average concentration of Sulfur dioxide from 1956 to 1974.[image: Sulfur dioxide average concentration]

The following graph shows the values of monthly maxima as "x" and yearly maxima as "o".
[image: Observed d.f. of monthly maxima (x), yearly maxima (o) from 1956 to 1974]

Now, assuming a double exponential distribution for annual maximum, one can estimate parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by maximum-likelihood method. The parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ were calculated by an variant of the least-squares method, so: $\alpha = 0.0824$ and $\beta=-2.6058$.

But now I have other values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. My step-by-step solution:

**1. To calculate $\beta$, I use the following formula:**

$$\beta=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2},$$

while $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $\bar{y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$.

$x_i$ are the sorted databases of annual maxima and $y_i$ are the databases of the empirical distribution function.

So: 
\begin{align*}
\bar{x} &= \frac{1}{19}\sum_{i=1}^{19} x_i = \frac{1}{19}\cdot 721 = 37.9474.\\
\bar{y} &= \frac{1}{19}\sum_{i=1}^{19} y_i = \frac{1}{19}\cdot 9.5 = 0.5.\\
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2 &= 3082.9474.\\
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y}) &= 64.55.\\
\Rightarrow \beta &= \frac{64.55}{3082.9474}= 0.0209.
\end{align*}

**2. To calculate $\alpha$, I use the following formula:**

$$\alpha = \bar{y}-\beta\cdot\bar{x}.$$

So, $\alpha = 0.5-0.0209\cdot 37.9474=-0.2945$ and $y=\alpha+\beta\cdot x =-0.2945+0.0209\cdot x$

**3. Drawing $(x_i,y_i)$ with the linear regression $y=\alpha+\beta\cdot x$:**

[image]

Could you help me, where my mistake is, please?

Comment: I suspect the formula you are using to fit your  linear regression result from a least-square method which is equivalent to maximizing likelihood only in case of assumed Gaussian (normal) statistics. They do not take into account of any exponential law.

Comment: Subsidiary question: does exponential law means Gaussian law in your text ?

Comment: Anyway if you assume gaussian statistics for your database your formulae for linear regression sound good.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found out how they calculate $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{i}{n+1}&=\exp(-\exp(-\alpha x_i-\beta))\\
\Leftrightarrow -\ln\left(\frac{i}{n+1} \right) &=\exp(-\alpha x_i-\beta)\\
\Leftrightarrow y_i:=-\ln\left(-\ln\left(\frac{i}{n+1} \right)\right) &=\alpha x_i+\beta.
\end{align*}

And with the least-square method, I've got

$$\alpha=0.0824,\qquad\beta=-2.6058.$$
EDIT: I got it!
[image]

Last question: How can I get the orange line as a straight line in Excel?

Comment: Take care with this linearization. What is measured is not $y$. You have estimates. Now, start a nonlinear regression. By the way, could you give me the data $(x_i,y_i)$; I would like to look at the full problem and I shall report the results to you.